# Not able to get the HTML code of the Ambition box website

Tags: python, html, machine-learning, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I used the code:

```
# google chrome browser's request header (to make it look like, we are making this request from a browser)
header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"
}
# hit using the header
response = requests.get("https://www.ambitionbox.com/list-of-companies?page=1", headers=header)
# see the recieved page source
response.text[0:500]
```

I was expecting:

```html
<!doctype html>\n<html data-n-head-ssr lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%22ssr%22:%22en%22%7D%7D">\n  <head >\n    <meta charset="UTF-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">\n    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> \n    \n    <script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),NREUM.init={distributed_tracing:{enabled:!0}},window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(n,r,t){function o(e){if(!r[e]){var t=r[e]={exports:{}};n[e][0].call(t
```

But I got:

```
\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n    <meta charset="utf-8">\n    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">\n    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=\'/list-of-companies?page=1&bm-verify=AAQAAAAH_____276GjTiSUrRZ57bXtQd2QOqDb6yzCSiw3txyMphpYFQNCJPEdUs0V5AOZD9bqWb9kr6Fp7sjO7l20QoJ9Br0-xif5TA0H7wrtpMZ81GeXv3aVnX5j-O5O3cZwHTOBn_dSsnlYEIfuZiiSi2pzTSogOOO9mPfZvC5y_WwYEtvkCBs7uPmtd4u17HOLEp6QC_7lIMkx77-pvpYjJ0FToKiIka8JU0IKmf95a5XjSIf_xu7Qv-GDvEwZqgJWfz
```

1
​

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're dealing with an anti-scrap protection that seems to redirect to another page after 5 seconds: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;`.

In your case, there are a few improvements that could help you get around it:

1. Use a more complete header with a different type of user agent, for example with a more complete string.
2. Or simulate a real browser using a python library like selenium for example.
3. Add a rule to accept the redirection, the requests documentation gives the `allow_redirects` function to do this

But don't forget, if there is anti-scraping protection, it may be for a good reason.